# Открыть и закрыть аудио файл. Ошибка: "wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id"

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, wav

Есть функция загрузки аудио:

```
async def upload_audio_message(api, multipart_data, peer_id):
    """Upload audio file `multipart_data` and return Attachment for sending to user with id `peer_id`(possibly)"""

    sender = api.get_default_sender("docs.getMessagesUploadServer")
    client = api.get_current_sender("docs.getMessagesUploadServer", sender=sender)

    data = aiohttp.FormData()
    data.add_field('file', multipart_data, filename="message.mp3", content_type='multipart/form-data')

    values = {'type': "audio_message", 'peer_id': peer_id}

    if client.group_id:
        values['group_id'] = client.group_id

    response = await api(sender=sender).docs.getMessagesUploadServer(**values)

    if not response or not response.get('upload_url'):
        return None

    upload_url = response['upload_url']

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess:
        async with sess.post(upload_url, data=data) as resp:
            result = json.loads(await resp.text())

    if not result:
        return None

    data = dict(file=result['file'])
    result = (await api(sender=sender).docs.save(**data))[0]

    return Attachment.from_upload_result(result, "doc")
```

Пытаюсь открыть аудио файл что бы загрузить его но что-то я делаю не так помогите пожалуйста:

```
answer_file = wave.open(self.get_path("winer.mp3"), "rb")
audio = await upload_audio_message(self.api, answer_file, msg.user_id)
answer_file.close()
```

> raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
>   wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Comment: А ваша либа поддерживает mp3? Видя сообщение - скорее всего нет.

Comment: Мне кажется дело не только в ней а еще в моем коде

Comment: Название методов похоже на vk :) Автор, а точно нужно парсить файл? Мб нужно просто считать и отправить его? Попробуйте: `answer_file = open(self.get_path("winer.mp3"), "rb")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка:

> wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Используемый модуль [wave](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/wave.html) умеет работать только с форматом `WAV`, поэтому в этом коде возникает та ошибка:

```
answer_file = wave.open(self.get_path("winer.mp3"), "rb")
```